# Unable to catch, when a user cancels MetaMask transaction

Tags: javascript, typescript, web3js, metamask

Here is my code example:

```js
const userAccount = '0x...';

// Call the contract method helloWorld()
const transaction = this.contract.methods
  .helloWrold('some parameter 1', 'some parameter 2')
  .send({ from: userAccount });

// Handle errors from the transaction
transaction.on('error', (error: any) => {
  console.error('Transaction error:', error);
});

// Handle success
transaction.on('receipt', (receipt: any) => {
  console.log('Transaction success:', receipt);
});
```

When the `send()` method is executed then `MetaMask`'s popup appears.
And the problem is, if a user cancels the transaction by pressing cancel in that popup.

My error handler is not executed. I have tried to use different events, I have tried to use `try...catch` block, but that doesn't seems to work with an async functions.

Is there any solution on this?

All I can see - that is the error in the console, that comes from MetaMask, that the user has denied to sign the transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have caught the error, using this code:

```js
window.ethereum
  .request({
    method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
    params: [
      {
        from: wallet,
        gas: '0x2dc6c0',
        gasPrice: '0x2540be400',
        to: this.contract.options.address,
        data: this.contract.methods
          .deploy('Hello World', this.generateSalt())
          .encodeABI(),
      },
    ],
  })
  .then((transactionHash: any) => {
    console.log('Transaction hash:', transactionHash);
  })
  .catch((error: any) => {
    if (error.code === 4001) {
      console.log('User denied transaction signature.');
      // Handle the case where the user denies the transaction signature
    } else {
      console.error('Another Error:', error);
      // Handle other errors
    }
  });
```

Comment: I would like to add a thing, that I have discovered today. There is a way to catch it. you need to check. error.interError.code === 4001. It seems that web3 library modifies the error object. my code looks like this:  `web3!.eth.sendTransaction(params).then(()=>{}).catch((error) => { if(error?.innerError?.code === 4001) {console.log('User has cancelled the transaction');} })`

Comment: But it seems, this approach also lacks the information about transaction events. I still have to parse logs.... The initial way with `.send` did proveide events, but I am not able to capture cancel user transaction that way.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem using send function.
I solved that using callback function to send function. Like this.

```
ethereum.send({
  method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
  params: [{"from": accounts[0],
  "to": smartContractaddress,
  "gas": "0x2DC6C0", // 30400
  "gasPrice": "0x2540BE400", 
  "value": weitohex, // 2441406250
  "data": inputhex}],
  from: accounts[0],
},function(err, transactionHash) {
  if (!err){
    console.log(transactionHash); 
    if(transactionHash.result !== undefined){
      document.getElementById('span_metalink').innerText="https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/"+transactionHash.result;
      document.getElementById('span_metalink').href="https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/"+transactionHash.result;
      document.getElementById('span_success').innerText = "Transaction Successfully Done!!!";
    }
    else{
      document.getElementById('span_success').innerText = "User denied transaction signature.";
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I have tried to use the callback function as well, it is not executed as well, when user presses cancel in MetaMask popup

Comment: I used it like this: `const transaction = this.contract.methods.helloWrold('some parameter 1', 'some parameter 2').send({ from: userAccount }, (a, b) => console.log('not called when user cancels'));`

Comment: What is the version of Metamask?

Comment: The version is 11.7.5

Comment: I am trying your method, but I get error: `VM361:1 MetaMask - RPC Error: Invalid input. {code: -32000, message: 'Invalid input.'}`

Comment: If I use the same parameters for window.ethereum.sendTransaction or the code I've posted in this question - then there is no such error and the Metamask prompts for transaction to be sent.
With your approach - Metamask does not trigger at all and I see the error in the browser's console

Comment: Oh I see, I used a single object as params, I should wrap it as array. now it works. And i catch the error using .catch(), because the request() returns a promise, there is no need to pass the second argument as a function, I will post an answer

Answer (score 0):

Without having tested this, I suspect this is because your are trying to catch transaction errors while the user rejecting the transaction might be handled differently.

Try adding a catch around

```
// Call the contract method helloWorld()
const transaction = this.contract.methods
  .helloWrold('some parameter 1', 'some parameter 2')
  .send({ from: userAccount });
```

Comment: As I wrote, try catch seems not to be working with async functions. Your suggestion will not work, and I already have tested it.

Comment: Yes, you have to await the promise if you want to catch it. But if the error is thrown and not fired through a handler then there is no other way to catch it.

Comment: Based on what I see here, unless I am missing something because web3js's code is huge, it seems like this type of error will not be passed to the handlers

These are the types of errors that will be send to the handlers https://github.com/web3/web3.js/blob/4.x/packages/web3-eth/src/utils/send_tx_helper.ts#L242

And this is the transaction rejected error https://github.com/web3/web3.js/blob/a0d4d2ea10f2269f61f364e1d5451d44b738c2b9/packages/web3-errors/src/errors/rpc_errors.ts#L157

So unless I am missing something you will not get it in the handlers

Comment: Yes, thats right. I can't get the event when user just cancels the MetaMask popup.